# Fetch a data from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this as a string. I have get this using jquery and parsing it from a web page.

I tried using jQuery.parseJSON and got the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token n`.

I need to get "surl" and "imgurl" how can I get this?

```
{
    ns:"images",
    k:"5061",
    mid:"172E23D582B8C2A90F3FE9DC2B04A3ECD1D4F70F",
    surl:"http://polyhouse2011.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/safety-precautions-2/",
    imgurl:"http://polyhouse2011.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/safety_gear1.gif",
    ow:"480",
    docid:"608038082569896450",
    oh:"301",
    tft:"117",
    dls:"images,5487"
}
```

Source of this string:

```
<a href="#" q="{ns:"images",k:"5061",mid:"172E23D582B8C2A90F3FE9DC2B04A3ECD1D4F70F",surl:"http://polyhouse2011.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/safety-precautions-2/",imgurl:"http://polyhouse2011.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/safety_gear1.gif",ow:"480",docid:"608038082569896450",oh:"301",tft:"117",dls:"images,5487"}"></a>
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON, the identifiers need to be quoted, i.e. "ns":"images".

Comment: okay so how can I sort this out as I have no way to change this string?

Comment: Hang on. jQuery parses the JSON data automatically on `.getJSON` and `.ajax` requests and returns an actual object, so you should just be able to do `response.surl` without you having to parse it. Looks like your trying to parse an object which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: @kannu can you share some code showing how you retrieve that "string"?

Comment: @Andy it is not from ajax request, ci:  the data is added in a anchor tag and I have to pick it up from there.

Comment: Then you need to ask whoever's in charge of populating that attribute to give you JSON that actually parses.

Comment: @Andy check the source of the string added in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My example assumes your anchor has an id for convenience. If [you use wrxsti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30124825/1377002) without all the unnecessary escaping, you get this:

```
var str = document.getElementById('a').getAttribute('q');
var json = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + str + ")"));
var obj = JSON.parse(json)
var surl = obj.srl;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rht5ru1s/)

But you really should get that attribute data changed to proper parsing JSON.

Comment: The escaping was purely because I like to look at JSON the way its meant to be formatted, but I know he has it in a string so it's just preference on my part. Plus the HTML part wasnt in the question when I answered.

Comment: Why thank you sir. Knowing the HTML part your answer is more elegant anyways :)

Comment: Thanks this worked, I also upvoted @wrxsti. And I do not know HTML is important for this, thought string only will do it..

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have the option of editing the JSON information you can do this to make it a valid json object. I will say that including eval can be bad due to security reasons, but this will make your JSON a valid object in the long run.

```
var object = '{ \
    ns: "images", \
    k: "5061", \
    mid: "172E23D582B8C2A90F3FE9DC2B04A3ECD1D4F70F", \
    surl: "http://polyhouse2011.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/safety-precautions-2/", \
    imgurl: "http://polyhouse2011.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/safety_gear1.gif", \
    ow: "480", \
    docid: "60808082569896450", \
    oh: "301", \
    tft: "117", \
    dls: "images5487" \
}';

var json = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + object + ")"));
var o = $.parseJSON(json);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hp34g6wt/3/)

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

this is a valid your JSON string :

```
{
    "ns": "images",
    "k": "5061",
    "mid": "172E23D582B8C2A90F3FE9DC2B04A3ECD1D4F70F",
    "surl": "http://polyhouse2011.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/safety-precautions-2/",
    "imgurl": "http://polyhouse2011.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/safety_gear1.gif",
    "ow": "480",
    "docid": "608038082569896450",
    "oh": "301",
    "tft": "117",
    "dls": "images,5487"
}
```

if you get some error in your JSON string then check its validation online  through http://jsonlint.com/   i hope it will help you.

Comment: Not an answer to the question. Read it again.

Comment: @ci_ I read that question and i got the error in json string. So i answered about valid json string and now if parse that string , can easily access surl and imgurl value.

Answer (score 1):

You use `object` format not `json` format, it is correct if you do like the following code:

```
var obj = {
    ns:"images",
    k:"5061",
    mid:"172E23D582B8C2A90F3FE9DC2B04A3ECD1D4F70F",
    surl:"http://polyhouse2011.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/safety-precautions-2/",
    imgurl:"http://polyhouse2011.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/safety_gear1.gif",
    ow:"480",
    docid:"608038082569896450",
    oh:"301",
    tft:"117",
    dls:"images,5487"
}
```

Therefore, if you want to get `surl` and `imgurl`: just do: `obj.surl;` and `obj.imgurl`